# How to check if a table will fit in current page or get split up in two pages in itext7

Tags: itext, itext7

I am trying to create a table in a PDF document with itext7. But, if the content before the table is too big, the table gets split up between current page and next page. I want to insert a -

```
document.Add(new AreaBreak())
```

if there is not enough space left in the current page for the table to be inserted completely. However, I have no idea on how to calculate the available space.

Any help or pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

From your requirement to avoid page-break inside the table, I assume `Table#setKeepTogether(boolean)` is exactly what you need.

This property ensures that, if it's possible, elements with this property are pushed to the next area if they are split between areas.

This is not exactly what you have asked, however it seems it's what you want to achieve. Manually checking for this use case might be tricky. You would need to have a look at renderers mechanism and inner processing of iText layout in order to get available space left and space needed for the table. You would also need to take care of the cases like if table is to big to be fit on single page. Also `#setKeepTogether(boolean)` works when elements are nested inside each other.